# Creating a 'new' instance solves destructor crash?

Tags: c++, destructor, delete-operator

I created a sub-class, B, for a class that I'll call A.

I wrote this code for work, so I'm going to generalize the actual code:

```
class A
{
public:
  A ()
     {
     important_variable = new Type();
     ...
     };

  ~A (void) { delete(important_variable); };      // Default destructor
  // more methods

protected:
  Type        *important_variable;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
B() : A() { important_variable = another_var; }
~B() {};

Type *another_var;
};
```

Having this code for B caused my program to crash with an 'Unhandled Exception'.

Now, when I change the code for class B to this:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
B() : A() { another_var = new Type(); important_variable = another_var; }
~B() {};

Type *another_var;
};
```

The exception goes away.

I think that my original code for B caused my program to crash because A was trying to delete a variable that was still being pointed to by another variable. Is this reasoning correct? Why does the new code for B cause my program to work?

Comment: Your reasoning is probably correct (can't say without seeing more code). The second code works because you create a new object for each instance, so each time you delete one it doesn't step on the toes of the others. But your code has memory leaks. You can't just reassign a pointer without doing something about the object it used to point to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many flaws in your code, but the one most likely to cause a crash is this line:

```
important_variable = another_var;
```

`another_var` does not point anywhere that can be deleted. But `important_variable` is made to point to the same place, and then is deleted in `A`'s constructor.

Your "solution" masks the problem, at the cost of a memory leak. When you do this

```
another_var = new Type(); important_variable = another_var;
```

the original dynamically allocated `Type` object that `important_variable` pointed to is lost.

Besides that, you need to follow the [*rule of three*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: How can I get rid of the memory leak, still keeping the existing functionality?

Comment: @Undefined too many ways. Don't use dynamic allocation unless you understand how it works? But it really depends on what you want to do, which isn't clear from your code.

Comment: @juanchopanza would setting `important_var` directly to `new Type()` in my subclass' constructor, and neglecting to call the superclass constructor fix the problem?

Comment: @Undefined No, the base class' default constructor will get called anyway. Let the base class handle its own resources.

Answer (score 0):

new and delete are for handling heap allocations only. I suspect that in your first listing of class B, `another_var` is likely allocated on the stack and this is what is causing the exception in the destructor. Additionally, whenever you have a base class you really should make its destructor `virtual`.

Answer (score 0):

The original version crashed because you set `important_variable` to uninitialised `another_var` and then you tried to delete this uninitialised value.
In the "corrected" version you at least do not delete uninitialised variables, but still in contains memory leak - you assign newly allocated memory to `important_variable` and then immediately you assign to this variable the value of `another_var`, so the originally allocated memory is no longer accessible and will leak.